# how to customize grails restful controller error response

Tags: rest, grails, grails-controller

How do we customize grails **RestfulController** error response? For example one of my restful controller returning following response by default on error while trying to save object.

```
{
  "errors": 
  [
    {
       "object": "com.test.Task",
       "field": "description",
       "rejected-value": null,
       "message": "Property [description] of class [class com.test.Task] cannot be null"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to customize the response as bellow.

```
{
   "errors" : 
    {
       "message": "Property [description] of class [class com.test.Task] cannot be" 
    },
    {
       "message": "This is going to be any 2nd message"
    },
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

All you need is Register Custom Objects Marshallers on `org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors` class

```
def messageSource //inject messageSource

JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(ValidationErrors) { validationErrors ->
    def errors = [] //add all errors into this list
    validationErrors.target.errors.allErrors.each { error ->
        errors.add(messageSource.getMessage(error, null)) //get messages from properties file.
    }

    //return map with errors list
    return ["errors":errors]
}
```

Response will be:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Property [description] of class [class com.test.Task] cannot be",
        "This is going to be any 2nd message"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Internationalization` feature described [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#validationAndInternationalization). Add the following to your resource bundle `messages.properties`.

```
task.description.nullable = your message
```

or

```
com.test.Task.description.nullable = your message
```